# Notice: Функция wpdb::prepare вызвана неправильно. Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

На странице ошибки 404 выводится предупреждение

> Notice: Функция wpdb::prepare вызвана неправильно. В запросе ожидался
>   только один заполнитель, но был послан массив из множества
>   заполнителей. Дополнительную информацию можно найти на странице
>   «Отладка в WordPress». (Это сообщение было добавлено в версии 4.9.0.)
>   in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 4148

Ругается на эту часть

```
function gp_add_cpt_post_names_to_main_query( $query ) {
    // Bail if this is not the main query.
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }
    // Bail if this query doesn't match our very specific rewrite rule.
    if ( ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) || 2 !== count( $query->query ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // Bail if we're not querying based on the post name.
    if ( empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // Add CPT to the list of post types WP will include when it queries based on the post name.
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'services', 'kursy', 'info-stati', 'news', 'otzivi', 'actions', 'our-team' ) );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'gp_add_cpt_post_names_to_main_query' );
```

Как можно ее переписать, чтобы ошибка исчезла?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

Answer (score 0):

Видимо у Вас WP версии више 4.8.2 
и включен режим отладки.

> В запросе ожидался только один заполнитель, но был послан массив из множества заполнителей.

```
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'services', 'kursy', 'info-stati', 'news', 'otzivi', 'actions', 'our-team' ) );
```

функция для работы с бд $wpdb->prepare() ожидает 1 аргумент для замены 'post_type' , тут же передается массив.

передавайте только 1 аргумент.

Что бы получить точный и подробный стек ошибки php вместо встроенной функции WP 'doing_it_wrong_run'
можно временно "поломать" function _doing_it_wrong , например добавил символ в имя функции.

```
/wp-includes/functions.php
```